# How to convert .mat file into .pcd file using matlab tool or any other coding language

Tags: matlab, point-cloud-library

How to convert .mat file into .pcd file using matlab tool? please give me any code for that.

I have .mat file which is sementic segmented done using image label application and i saved in gtruth format. i wanted to convert that file into .pcd (point cloud data) format.

Comment: Load .mat file into Matlab and write to .pcd using `pcwrite` https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcwrite.html